# Terminal Up Key Simulation - enter text without running it

Tags: java, linux, command-line

I'm working on a project that simulates a clipboard for the Linux command line.

I am able to save commands to the virtual clipboard and print them back as output, but I would like to be able to automatically enter the returned string into the prompt instead of having it return as output.

For example, my goal is that running a command:

```
~$ foo -2
```

Would return the string specified by index 2 and input it into the command line just like I had hit the up key or **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>** so that the user can edit the command before running it if necessary.

I am writing in Java.  Is this even possible?

Comment: One solution could be to use [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), but the command window would need to have focus for this to work correctly.